# Sum the result of count()

Tags: sql

I have a table like this.

```js
-----------------
|City    |Block |
-----------------
|Bekasi  |A1    |
|Bekasi  |A1    |  
|Jakarta |A1    |
|Jakarta |A2    |
|Bandung |A3    |
-----------------
```

What is the correct query if I want to count subtotal of Bekasi's block as 1, Jakarta's block as 2 and Bandung's block as 1, so it will return total values like this?

```js
-----------------
|City    |Block |
-----------------
|Bekasi  |A1    |
|Bekasi  |A1    |  
|Jakarta |A1    |
|Jakarta |A2    |
|Bandung |A3    |
-----------------
|TOTAL   |4     |
-----------------
```

I tried using this query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT block) AS total FROM report GROUP BY city
```

But it will only return a result like this.

```js
--------
|Total |
--------
|1     |
|1     |  
|2     |
--------
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (etc mysql, oracle, mssql)

Comment: Did you want something like this: `SELECT sum(total) FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT block) AS total FROM report GROUP BY city) foo;` ?

Comment: @Arion I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the sum of the total count

```
select SUM(a.total)
from 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT block) AS total FROM report GROUP BY city) a
```

And if you want the data and total in the same query you could do something like this:

```
select 1 as rank, city, count(city) from report group by city
union all
select 2 as rank, 'Total', SUM(a.total)
from 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT block) AS total FROM report GROUP BY city) a
order by rank asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (t) from (
select city,count(block) as t from report group by city, block) s
group by city
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but it won't sum the result of count()

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select City,count(distinct Block) from report group by City With RollUp
```

Comment: Your code is so far from what I want it to be. But thank you for your response.